# Why are these MySQL queries so slow?

Tags: mysql, wordpress, mysql-slow-query-log

I don't understand why the following queries show up in slow query log with query time from 12 to 20 seconds.

```
UPDATE `wp_postmeta` SET `meta_value` = '35' WHERE `post_id` = 1267 AND `meta_key` = 'views'
UPDATE `wp_postmeta` SET `meta_value` = '32' WHERE `post_id` = 874 AND `meta_key` = 'views'
UPDATE `wp_postmeta` SET `meta_value` = '122' WHERE `post_id` = 18557 AND `meta_key` = 'views'
UPDATE `wp_postmeta` SET `meta_value` = '3078' WHERE `post_id` = 21741 AND `meta_key` = 'views'
UPDATE `wp_postmeta` SET `meta_value` = '2657' WHERE `post_id` = 878 AND `meta_key` = 'views'
```

They look pretty normal to me and executing 1 of them in phpMyAdmin for testing only takes 0.0056s.
The size of the `wp_postmeta` table here is 77,996.

I wonder why the above queries are so slow and if there is anything I can do to improve them?

Comment: What is the datatype of meta_value, if its integer than treat is as integer. It is always better to treat numbers as numbers, not strings

Comment: use primary index for the post_id column ! that will speed up

Comment: Hi @RanjitKumar, post_id is not unique here. Another column called `meta_id` has the primary key

Comment: Hi @abdulwakeel, `meta_value` is longtext here, thanks

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Better index to use than what @Sandeep suggested is:

```
CREATE INDEX <some index name>
ON wp_postmeta (meta_key, post_id);
```

This index will capture all the `WHERE` clauses and enable the database engine to quickly go to the right row.

Answer (score 4):

Create an index on column "post_id". It will solve your problem.

When data is huge, indexes play a significant role in query optimization.